# Angular 10 End Point(id) Is Not A Function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello my goal is to empty the shopping cart after transaction is a success. it works fine with one item(id) its when there is more than one item in cart.

I have a forEach method that according to document should take an arrow, using => typescript complains saying expected ",". I get an exception error 5 is not a function, 5 is the endpoint which is an id that I'm trying to delete .  I don't understand, I put this same code in a function that is called at onInit and it works fine.  I put it there merely for test purposes. But when I call this service from a function it blows up, throws an exception. The thing is it still deletes the id of the item it complains about when refresh the page. I tried with a function per the documentation but then  I get all types of errors still saying I need a comma(,).  Can someone please point me in the right direction as far as what I'm doing wrong? I would greatly appreciate it.

code snippet below:

cart service

```
  deleteCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
      return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
       map((result: any[]) => {
         
         let cartItems: CartItem[] =[];
          
 
         for(let item of result) {
         
            cartItems.push( new CartItem(item.id, item.size, item.product, item.imageUrl ));
              alert("whats in item" + item.id);
              this.cartIdsArray = cartItems.map(item => item.id)
               let id: number = item.id;
               let  endPoints = "/cart/" + id;
               //var  endPoints = "/cart/";
              this.cartIdsArray.forEach((item.id),this.http.delete(this.url + endPoints).subscribe(data=>{
               console.log(data);
              })
              
      )
             
            
        }
          
         return cartItems;
         
        })
      );
 
         
    }
```

Comment: That is not valid TypeScript code, it will not compile.

Comment: This does compile I just gave you a snippet of the code to tell you where I'm have the issue and that is with the foreEach method

Comment: Then you need to provide the source of the `forEach` method, because it's obviously not standard. The built in method with the same name accepts only one argument.

Comment: I did an edit to show full function and it does compile

Comment: A big mess.... incomprehensible code. Why are you refilling `this.cartIdsArray` on each iteration? And what's this? `this.cartIdsArray.forEach((item.id),this.http.delete......` never seen this code structure

Comment: I'm sure I understand, the forEach method is there even before the edit

Comment: OK, apparently the second argument to the `forEach` function is an optional `thisArg` so I stand corrected. As to the problem in the code: I think you meant something like `.forEach(id => this.http.delete(this.url + endPoints /* +id here maybe? */).subscribe(...))` instead.

Comment: I am mapping all of the ids as to do one delete, to do this I copy the array.  As I stated above this works when I had it to my function that load on onInit for test purposes

Comment: Lets say I did it like this   this.cartIdsArray.forEach((item.id),this.http.delete(this.url + endPoints + id).subscribe(data=>{
               console.log(data); It still yields the same result

Comment: I tried the arrow function as I mentioned above typescript complains

Comment: When I try forEach without the "this" this.id and use just id the value is never read

Answer (score 1):

**10 End Point(id) Is Not A Function**

[Syntax of forEach() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach(callbackFn, thisArg)

The second optional parameter of forEach() is `thisArg`.

> I get an exception error 5 is not a function

The error is correct because the first parameter is supposed to be a function. It can be specified in a couple of different syntaxes arrow function, inline function or named function.

So, Javascript correctly errors out when you pass the number 5 as first parameter instead of actual function.

**Why does the API get called?**

The second parameter `thisArg` gets evaluated as a Javascript expression and it gets fired as a side effect.
See an tiny example of what's actually happening in your code.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var item = {
  id: 5
}

arr.forEach(item.id, console.log('deletion successful'))
```

[image]

Now, that the problem is understood fixing it is easier.

> it works fine with one item(id) its when there is more than one item in cart.

When `forEach()` method gets executed, it evaluates both the parameters causing the delete API to be called and raises an error after when it sees that the first parameter is not a function. As the error is not caught it stops the execution of the deleteCartItems() method. The remaining items in the `cartIdsArray` never get processed.

**Refactored solution 1**

1. You do not need to iterate over the complete list of results as there's a loop already.
2. new CartItem() instance is not needed.
3. There are lot of subscriptions created which results in memory leak.
   [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vue7lp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

   ```
   deleteCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
   const cartUrl = 'https://62c41dc97d83a75e39f0d512.mockapi.io/api/v1/cart';
   return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
     tap((cartItems: CartItem[]) => {
       cartItems.forEach((cartItem) => {
         this.http
           .delete(this.url + '/cart/' + cartItem.id)
           .pipe(first())
           .subscribe();
       });
       return cartItems;
     })
   );
   ```

   }

**Refactored solution 2**

We do not need to use Array `forEach()` method by using Array `map()` method
You can actually use `forkJoin()` operator to make parallel API calls. Also, `map()` operator is not actually needed as you are not transforming the result, `tap()` is a better candidate as you want a side effect
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jxbvby?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
deleteCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
    const cartUrl = 'https://62c41dc97d83a75e39f0d512.mockapi.io/api/v1/cart';
    return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      tap((cartItems: CartItem[]) => {
        forkJoin(
          cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
            this.http.delete(this.url + '/cart/' + cartItem.id).pipe(first())
          )
        ).subscribe();
        return cartItems;
      })
    );
  }
```

**Refactored solution 3**

Nested `subscribe()` is still bad and can be removed as below.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5mplub?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
    deleteCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
    const cartUrl = 'https://62c41dc97d83a75e39f0d512.mockapi.io/api/v1/cart';
    return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      first(),
      mergeMap(cartItems => {
        return forkJoin(
          cartItems.map((cartItem) =>
            this.http.delete<CartItem>(this.url + '/cart/' + cartItem.id).pipe(first())
          )
        )
      })
    )
  }
```

Note: I have left error handling as an exercise, but it should be done for a real project.

Comment: Hi Phalgun. I like the way you handled my question, I did look at the documentation and the way you explain it, it makes since.  When I did it with out the item , when I hover over it, it says value is never read.

Comment: Hi Phalgun, Since the id is never read can it will keep going thru loop until it throws an exception. Now I have to figure out why the value is never read. This is of course using the arrow function per the documentation.

Comment: I have created a sample application around the function you provided with API call.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x4poxw?file=src/app/app.component.ts.

I did not understand, "When I did it with out the item , when I hover over it, it says value is never read", where did you see "value is never read". It would be good if you can add a screenshot where you see "value is never read"

Comment: Hi Phalgun, I saw it when I hover over id but I figured that part out. I had to break my endpoint down.  Thank you so much.  We as developers come to stackoverflow to collaborate with other developers such as your self.  I'm working on a huge application alone. This application has several api's .  I have one with PayPal as well only the buttons.  I'm responsible for making  it work with my cart.  This is the last piece.  I have struggled but learned a lot. Thank you again, its always the small things that hold us up.  I will remember your name. Endurance pays off.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some opportunities for refactoring. You might want to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified code snippet (pure Typescript, mock data, no Angular and no service calls) that I think is what you're trying to achieve. Focus on what the loop does and how to finally repeatedly call the service in the last `forEach`. If I'm correct then you can change your code accordingly.

```
class CartItem {
    id: number;
}

const result = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] as CartItem[];
const cartItems: CartItem[] = [];

for (let item of result) {
    cartItems.push({ id: item.id });
    console.log("whats in item " + item.id);
    this.cartIdsArray = cartItems.map(item => item.id);
}
this.cartIdsArray.forEach(id => {
    const endPoint = "/cart/" + id;
    console.log(id, endPoint);
});
```

Or even simpler:

```
class CartItem {
    id: number;
}

const result = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] as CartItem[];
const cartItems: number[] = [];

for (let item of result) {
    console.log("whats in item " + item.id);
    cartItems.push(item.id);
}
cartItems.forEach(id => {
    const endPoint = "/cart/" + id;
    console.log(id, endPoint);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
deleteCartItems() {
  return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      concatAll(),
      map((item) => new CartItem(item.id, item.size, item.product, item.imageUrl)),
      mergeMap((item) => this.deleteCartItemById(item.id).pipe(map(item))),
      toArray(),
  );
}

deleteCartItemById(id: number) {
  return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/cart/${id}`);
}
```